# I tied to make insert in Laravel but i got this error

Tags: laravel-8

TypeError In Response.php line 466 :
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setStatusCode(): Argument #1 ($code) must be of type int, string given, called in /Users/me/Talabv2/dbf.dbestech.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php on line 39
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsnWg.jpg)

```
namespace Illuminate\Http;

use ArrayObject;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable;
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use JsonSerializable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response as SymfonyResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

class Response extends SymfonyResponse
{
    use ResponseTrait, Macroable {
        Macroable::__call as macroCall;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $content
     * @param  int  $status
     * @param  array  $headers
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function __construct($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = [])
    {
        $this->headers = new ResponseHeaderBag($headers);

        $this->setContent($content);


        
        $this->setStatusCode($status);
        $this->setProtocolVersion('1.0');
    }

    /**
     * Set the content on the response.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $content
     * @return $this
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->original = $content;

        // If the content is "JSONable" we will set the appropriate header and convert
        // the content to JSON. This is useful when returning something like models
        // from routes that will be automatically transformed to their JSON form.
        if ($this->shouldBeJson($content)) {
            $this->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            $content = $this->morphToJson($content);

            if ($content === false) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(json_last_error_msg());
            }
        }

        // If this content implements the "Renderable" interface then we will call the
        // render method on the object so we will avoid any "__toString" exceptions
        // that might be thrown and have their errors obscured by PHP's handling.
        elseif ($content instanceof Renderable) {
            $content = $content->render();
        }

        parent::setContent($content);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given content should be turned into JSON.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $content
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function shouldBeJson($content)
    {
        return $content instanceof Arrayable ||
               $content instanceof Jsonable ||
               $content instanceof ArrayObject ||
               $content instanceof JsonSerializable ||
               is_array($content);
    }

    /**
     * Morph the given content into JSON.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $content
     * @return string
     */
    protected function morphToJson($content)
    {
        if ($content instanceof Jsonable) {
            return $content->toJson();
        } elseif ($content instanceof Arrayable) {
            return json_encode($content->toArray());
        }

        return json_encode($content);
    }
}
```

this code where the error appears

Comment: Ca n you post the complete call to the response class with the parameter $status ?

Comment: It is said that you are passing a STRING in your ```$code``` variable that is not included in your code above. Make sure that the value of your *$code* should be an interger. *EX:($code = 5)*. If you are passing a number in a string type, *EX:($code = "5")*, Just convert it with an interger by doing ```$code = (int)"5"```.